# Finding all quadratic tuple of subsets for a given set

Tags: combinatorics

I'm studying for an exam of a sort and I ran into this problem:
Find the size of $Q$ when $Q=\{(A,B,C,D)|A,B,C,D\subseteq\ \{1,...,n\}\bigwedge A \cup B\cup C\cup D=\{1,...,n\}\}$
I have no idea how to approach so any hintqidea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the set of numbers instead of the 4 sets. Suppose we have $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then $k$ must belong to at least one of the four possible sets, but possibly more. The numbers of combinations of sets for this number to be a part of is 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{4}\binom{4}{i} = 2^4 - 1.
\end{equation}
Now for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have the same situation, thus the total number of possibilities is $(2^4-1)^n$. Note that I assumed that a set in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is allowed to be empty, which is set theoretically true, but I am unsure whether that is supposed to be allowed in the exercise.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)